# How to do a VLOOKUP in another Google sheet based on a filtered value?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

Basically I have a list of cars that I wish to hypothetically sell and captured the data in the Cars tab in [this google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hfU3FSUTNqIr76giOE9r8jKBeifg5iuMdsCVnaZ5RLw/edit?usp=sharing).

What I am trying to do is capture how many cars are for sale based on the car type and also consumer interest based on the car type. For example, how many "Y" the sports car has and store this total in a new tab called Consumer stats in [this google sheet.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hfU3FSUTNqIr76giOE9r8jKBeifg5iuMdsCVnaZ5RLw/edit?usp=sharing)

I dont know how to do a VLOOKUP so it extracts all the Y for consumer interest based on sports car for example

Any help will really mean a lot!

Thanks

Comment: Excel is not Google Sheets. If you have a question about Sheets, why are you including the Excel tag?

Comment: @BigBen Cool. Do you know the answer to the question?

Comment: Using COUNTIFS maybe? Not sure what you mean by "extracts". Or maybe FILTER.

Comment: @BigBen So essentially I want to take all the Y for a sports car for example, count the number of Y's for sports car and store that value in a new tab.

Comment: Then use COUNTIFS as I demonstrated in your sheet.

Comment: @BigBen Thanks mate, perfect!! How do I put that number in a new tab? Can you see I have a new tab called "Consumer Stats". How do I put that number in that  "Consumer Stats"? Thanks

Comment: Did your issue get solved? What's currently in `Consumer Stats` seems to be what you want to do. If that's not the case, can you indicate the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a pivot table?  This seems like the perfect use case.

In your example sheet, I added 3 versions.

1. Your original ask, count of consumer interest by car type
2. Count of consumer interest by car type and model
3. Type and Model that have both interest and are for sale.

There are multiple tutorials online for how to set up pivot tables.

The pivot table can be more powerful if you used 0 and 1 for N and Y in your interest and for sale.  Sheet's pivot tables don't do COUNTIF natively, and adding custom formulas seems like a lot of extra work.